# How can I get the command log of a particular user on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, command-line, users, logging

Is there a way to find a log of all the commands that have been run by a user on Ubuntu 11.10 Server?
I need to find out what my friend ran to install a program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use something like bash as a command interpreter, you could check the history.

```
more /home/user/.bash_history
```

Comment: How can i check the history with time-stamp? When each commands were used?

Comment: Under what conditions are commands added to the log? I've read that the commands are only added to the log when you exit. I noticed my commands weren't being added so I thought maybe it was because I was being kicked rather than exiting. Then I tried existing and even the they weren't added. I ask because I'm only seeing a few commands from early on in my new Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score -2):

Follow these instructions (revised from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207813/how-to-log-every-command-typed-into-bash-and-every-file-operation/207819#207819)).

1. Modify the `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. Append the below line the end of that file

   ```
    export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/[ ][0-9]+[ ]//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
   ```
3. Create a new file

   ```
   /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf
   ```
4. Add the line to the file

   ```
   local6.*    /var/log/commands.log
   ```
5. Add line to the file  `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` .

   Nearby:

   ```
   /var/log/mail.warn
   /var/log/mail.err
   [...]
   /var/log/message
   ```

   Add this

   ```
   /var/log/commands.log
   ```
6. Restart the rsyslog.

   ```
   sudo service rsyslog restart
   ```

Comment: This seems to be a bad copy of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207819/130000, and this is not an answer to the question about command already issued